# Python win32com VBA UserForm object Caption property set

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I am trying to create Excel VBA UserForm using Win32com in Python. I am able to add the UserForm to a workbook, I can even add controls to this form, however I am stuck with updating the properties of the UserForm object itself. For example: I can read the Caption property using the below code, but I had no luck setting it.
Does anyone know how to set VBA UserForm properties in Python using win32com?

My Code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

com_object = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xlFile = com_object.Workbooks.Open(Filename = 'MyExcelFileaPath.xlsx')
xlForm = xlFile.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3) 
print (xlForm.Properties('Caption')) #this works
xlForm.Properties('Caption') = 'Custom Caption' #this does not work - error: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
xlForm.Properties.Caption = 'Custom Caption' #this does not work
```

Comment: Maybe try `xlForm.Properties.Item('Caption') = 'Custom Caption'`

Comment: Thanks, but this throws the same error - "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call". There must be a different method or property to be used on xlForm object that allows setting the properties such as 'Caption'. I have searched for 2 days and even was able to find the code that can list COMobject methods, but could not figure out further. Looks like it's being kept secrete for some reason :)

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72272390/win32com-cannot-assign-to-function-call

Comment: I have tried the described solution by adding different variations of: `xlForm.setCaption('Custom Caption')`, but it give AttributeError. I have been digging into a new direction, trying to create a custom EXCEL class with self.xlForm object and by setting the custom __getattr__ and __setattr__, it allows handling the errors, but ultimately I am still unable to set any of the UserForm properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a week of research, trial and error I came up with a way to set UserForm object's properties. As I suspected, the answer is kind of silly:

```
xlForm.Properties('Caption').Value = 'Custom Caption'
```

Hope this helps someone to save some time.